# Want to add an exception on add to cart button

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, exception

I am building an ecommerce site name bookslab.in. I want to add the exception on add to cart button. If the zip code of the users are invalid then i want a pop message that says "Your zipcode is invalid so can't buy the product". I had a exception in zipcode field. I am providing the cod.phtml  & view.phtml programs.

cod.phtml

```
<?php
/***************************************
 *** Cash On Delivery ***
 ***************************************
 *
 */

$msgData = Mage::helper('netgo_cod')->getConfigData(); 
if($msgData['zip_status'] == 1){
?>
<div class="input-box">
    <div class="z-btn">
        <label>Zip Code : </label><input type="text" placeholder="Enter your pincode" value="" name="cod" class="product-custom-option required-entry" id="cod" size="29" style='color:black; font-size:12px'>
        <button type="button" onclick="checkCOD();" name="zip-check" title="Check" class="button" id="zip-check"><span><span>Check</span></span></button>
    </div>
    <div id="cod_msg"></div>
</div>

<script>
    function checkCOD(){
             var zipcode;
        var cod = $('cod').value;
        if(cod == ''){
            $('cod_msg').update('<span class="cod-error"><?php echo $msgData['emp_msg']; ?></span>');
            return
        }else{
            $('cod_msg').update('<img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl( Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB, true ).'media/cod/img/ajax-loader-2.gif';?>">'); 
            new Ajax.Request('<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().'netgo/cod/check';?>', {
                method:'post',
                parameters: {zipcode: cod}, 
                onSuccess: function(transport) {
                    var response = transport.responseText || "no response text";
                    $('cod_msg').update(response);

                    if(response.search('Delivery of the book is not available on the above pincode')!=-1)
                                        {
                                          zipcode='checked';
                                        }
                                      else
                                      {
                                      zipcode='';
                                      }

                },
                onFailure: function() { alert('Something went wrong...'); }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

view.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 */
?>
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script>
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?></div>
<div class="product-view">
    <div class="product-essential">
        <form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product, array('_secure' => $this->_isSecure())) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
            <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
            <div class="no-display">
                <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
            </div>

            <div class="product-img-box">
                <div class="product-name">
                    <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
                </div>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
            </div>

            <div class="product-shop">
                <div class="product-name">
                    <span class="h1"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></span>
                </div>

                <div class="price-info">
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bundle_prices') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
                </div>

                <div class="extra-info">
                    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'default', false)?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_availability'); ?>
                </div>

                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>

                <?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
                    <div class="short-description">
                        <div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
                    </div>
                <?php endif;?>




                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other');?>

                <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
                <?php endif;?>

            </div>

            <div class="add-to-cart-wrapper">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>

                <?php if (!$this->hasOptions()):?>
                    <div class="add-to-box">
                        <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                            <?php if( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || $_compareUrl=$this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)): ?>
                                <span class="or"><?php echo $this->__('OR') ?></span>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sharing') ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_buttons') ?>
                <?php elseif (!$_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <div class="add-to-box">
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sharing') ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>

            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('related_products') ?>

            <div class="clearer"></div>
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
            <?php endif;?>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
            var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
            productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
                if (this.validator.validate()) {
                    var form = this.form;
                    var oldUrl = form.action;

                    if (url) {
                       form.action = url;
                    }
                    var e = null;
                    try {

                    this.form.submit();

                     } catch (e) {
                    }
                    this.form.action = oldUrl;
                    if (e) {
                        throw e;
                    }

                    if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                        button.disabled = true;
                    }
                }
            }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

            productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
                if(this.validator) {
                    var nv = Validation.methods;
                    delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
                    delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
                    delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
                    // Remove custom datetime validators
                    for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
                        if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
                            delete Validation.methods[methodName];
                        }
                    }

                    if (this.validator.validate()) {
                        if (url) {
                            this.form.action = url;
                        }
                        this.form.submit();
                    }
                    Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
                }
            }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
        //]]>
        </script>
    </div>

    <div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">
        <?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
            <dl id="collateral-tabs" class="collateral-tabs">
                <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $alias => $html):?>
                    <dt class="tab"><span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getChildData($alias, 'title')) ?></span></dt>
                    <dd class="tab-container">
                        <div class="tab-content"><?php echo $html ?></div>
                    </dd>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </dl>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data') ?>

</div>
```

[image]

Comment: any answer stacky's!

Comment: Which your Magento version?

Comment: I am using version 1.9

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should create custom block class and add it to proper phtml in xmls. Block should contains some custom logic checking the zip-code of customer, basing on session (you can get customer object from session). Then, according to results of method checking zip-code you can add message in session with redirect to refererer page (so the same page where you trigger 'add to cart' button if customer's zip code is not proper.

Comment: Can u please suggest me in my code which is provided

Comment: your code contains only phtmls. Please read something about creating a custom Block class. Next take a look how to add your custom block to templates. Then you can search something about messages in session in Magento. You should find all information withuot problem in tutorials.

Comment: what type of tutorials you are talking abt?

Comment: any stacky's who suggest me in the code i provided